# Updating/Deleting a user's status updates

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a permission that will allow me to update the privacy of a user's news feed item (status update), or delete it. In the manual there is only documentation on how to delete posts that your application made. I can understand this, as I wouldn't want an application I'd installed messing with my posts in such a way that was not easy to trace.

However, my use-case is this. Stuck with a timeline where everyone can see my old posts, I had to put everyone on the restricted list. I'd like to change the visibility of all my posts so that only *I* can see them, and no-one else and then take everyone off restricted.

So, is there some way I can do this using the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating a post's privacy or deleting posts made by a different app aren't available via the API.  I spent hours cleaning this all up manually when timeline launched, and then I just ended up deactivating my account anyways.  The only way to do this programmatically would be to scrape their site or write some kind of greasemonkey script, both of which would probably violate their terms of service.